# calculating averages across array indices and collecting results to a new array

Tags: java, arrays, average

I'm trying to run the `averaged perceptron` which takes all the weight vectors created during each iteration and then, for instance, for the first index, it will take the average across all weights associated with index 1 in all of the iterations that preceded the converagance and use this average as the output value for the final weights result, i.e. this becomes the value for index 1 of the final output array.

so if the weights are:

iteration 1: `[5,10,20]`
iteration 2: `[3,4,6]`
iteration 3: `[2,9,12]`

resulting array: `[3.333,7.666,12.666]`

I tried to make code to perform this operation but what I get is this:

```
weights: 
[4.356800000000003, 0.5011, 0.502, 0.2078, 0.8042,

weights: 
[7.956800000000005, 0.5011, 0.402, 0.1078, 0.8042,             

average: 
[7.956800000000005, 0.5011, 0.402, 0.1078, 0.8042,
```

It's failing to take the average but merely replicating the last weight. What is the cause of this?! It seems to be that I specified the average calculation correctly but aparently not. Where have I gone awry?

The code looks like this:

```
  public static void perceptron( Table< int[] , String , Integer > train_freq_count_against_globo_dict,
                                 Table< int[] , String , Integer > test_freq_count_against_globo_dict,
                                 Set<String> GLOBO_DICT )
  {

       //store weights to be averaged. 
       Map<Integer,double[]> cached_weights = new HashMap<Integer,double[]>();  

      int globo_dict_size = GLOBO_DICT.size();
      int number_of_files__train = train_freq_count_against_globo_dict.size();

      double[] weights = new double[ globo_dict_size + 1 ];//one for bias
      for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) 
      {
        weights[i] = randomNumber(0,1);
      }     

      double[][] feature_matrix__train = new double[ number_of_files__train ][ globo_dict_size ];
      int[] outputs__train = new int [ number_of_files__train ];

      int z = 0;
      for ( Cell< int[] , String , Integer > cell: train_freq_count_against_globo_dict.cellSet() )
      {            
          int[] container_of_feature_vector = cell.getRowKey();

          for (int q = 0; q < globo_dict_size; q++) 
          {
               feature_matrix__train[z][q] = container_of_feature_vector[q];
           }
           outputs__train[z] = String.valueOf( cell.getColumnKey() ).equals(LABEL) ? 1 : 0;

           z++;
      }

      //LEARNING WEIGHTS
      double localError, globalError;
      int p, iteration, output;

      iteration = 0;
      do 
      {
          iteration++;
          globalError = 0;
          //loop through all instances (complete one epoch)
          for (p = 0; p < number_of_files__train; p++) 
          {
              // calculate predicted class
              output = calculateOutput( theta, weights, feature_matrix__train, p, globo_dict_size );
              // difference between predicted and actual class values
              localError = outputs__train[p] - output;
              //update weights and bias
              for (int i = 0; i < globo_dict_size; i++) 
              {
                  weights[i] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError * feature_matrix__train[p][i] );
              }
              weights[ globo_dict_size ] += ( LEARNING_RATE * localError );

              //summation of squared error (error value for all instances)
              globalError += (localError*localError);
          }

          System.out.println("weights: ");
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(weights));
          System.out.println();

          //store weights for averaging
          cached_weights.put( iteration , weights );
      } 
      while(globalError != 0 && iteration<=MAX_ITER);

      //compute averages
      double[] sums = new double[ globo_dict_size + 1 ];
      double[] averages = new double[ globo_dict_size + 1 ];

      for (Entry<Integer, double[]> entry : cached_weights.entrySet()) 
      {
           double[] value = entry.getValue();
           for(int pos=0; pos < globo_dict_size + 1; pos++)
           {
               sums[ pos ] +=  value[ pos ]; 
           }
       }
       for(int pos=0; pos < globo_dict_size + 1; pos++)
       {
           averages[ pos ] = sums[ pos ] / cached_weights.size(); 
       }
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand - can you show a simple and complete example that reproduces your problem?

Comment: @assylias I just posted the rest of the relevent code from that class, I think that should make it easier to follow, is it?

Comment: The code is extremely hard to read...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `do while` loop where you fill the Map with data to be averaged later. At the end of the loop you add the array `weights` to the map. But in fact this is the same array on every iteration.

So every iteration will overwrite the values of the existing `weights` array. The map contains x keys, but they all have a reference to the same array as value.

That's why in the end, when you try to calculate average values, you always get the values of the "last" array... because all entries of the map reference this same array and thus the average values are the same.

What you need to do is to create a new array inside the loop for every iteration. Seen that the values of the new array depend on the last array's values, you should copy the existing value like this (thanks @Soana for the input):

`weights = Arrays.copyOf(weights, weights.length);`

And then calculate new values for the new array.

I hope you understand what I mean. :-)

Comment: I don't think that he can just create a new `weights` array in each iteration, because the next iteration is dependent on this data from the previous iteration. `Arrays.copyOf(weights)` (or something similar) should work.

Comment: @Soana yes, right! I didn't dig too much into the logic of his algorithm, but noted that the problem is that he actually has just one array. So yes, creating a copy of the array on every iteration would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Taking your requirement as:

> so if the weights are:
>
> iteration 1: [5,10,20] iteration 2: [3,4,6] iteration 3: [2,9,12]
>
> resulting array: [3.333,7.666,12.666]

You can try the following method, which accepts any number of arrays:

```
private double[] averageArray(int[]... arrays) throws Exception
{
    // take the first array as starting point
    int[] sums = arrays[0].clone();

    for (int i = 1; i < arrays.length; i++)
    {
        // how can we take average if the inputs are different lengths!
        if (arrays[i].length != sums.length)
        {
            throw new Exception("Input arrays are of differing dimensions!");
        }
        // add this array to our running sum
        for (int j = 0; j < sums.length; j++)
        {
            sums[j] += arrays[i][j];
        }
    }
    double[] averages = new double[sums.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < sums.length; k++)
    {
        // cast to double to avoid integer division
        averages[k] = (double) sums[k] / arrays.length;
    }
    return averages;
}
```

This passes the following unit test which expresses your requirement:

```
@Test
public void averageTest() throws Exception
{
    int[] a = { 5, 10, 20 };
    int[] b = { 3, 4, 6 };
    int[] c = { 2, 9, 12 };

    Assert.assertArrayEquals(new double[] { 10.0 / 3, 23.0 / 3, 38.0 / 3 }, averageArray(a, b, c), 0);
}
```

This returns a double[] as per your code, but you might be better off with BigDecimals, especially as it looks like precision and accuracy is important to whatever you're attempting.

As others have mentioned, your code is very difficult to read, and in particular could use better parameter naming.